# iOS: MPMoviePlayerController Done button doesn't work

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, fullscreen

I am adding an MPMoviePlayerController to a view like so:

```
player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone; 
[player.view setFrame:self.playerView.bounds];     
[self.playerView addSubview:player.view];
```

self.playerView is a small view inside my main view and I have custom buttons that control playback within that same main view. This all works fine.

I have a fullscreen button that works like so:

```
- (IBAction) btnFullScreenPressed:(id)sender {
    [player setFullscreen:TRUE animated:TRUE];
    [player setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen];
}
```

This works fine, but then when I hit the Done button on the full screen controls, the movie stops playing but does not return to the smaller self.playerView in my view. How can I get it to "un-fullscreen" and return to the smaller self.playerView?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Quite unintuitively you actually have to set the control style to default, i.e.:

```
- (IBAction) btnFullScreenPressed:(id)sender {
    [player setFullscreen:TRUE animated:TRUE];
    [player setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleDefault];
}
```

and, of course, then set it back to none when you receive MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification or MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification (I prefer "did exit").

Comment: This didn't work for me. The video stops but it remains in full screen mode.